# How to get email addresses while fetching google contacts in angular 10

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, angular10, google-people-api

I am trying to get email of google contacts using people API and oAuth2.0. I am able to get all data except email. Any Suggestions

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import {
  GoogleApiModule, 
  GoogleApiService, 
  GoogleAuthService, 
  NgGapiClientConfig, 
  NG_GAPI_CONFIG,
  GoogleApiConfig
} from "ng-gapi";

let gapiClientConfig: NgGapiClientConfig = {
  client_id: "<Client_id>",
  discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest"],
  scope:[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
].join(" ")
};

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    GoogleApiModule.forRoot( {
            provide: NG_GAPI_CONFIG,
            useValue: gapiClientConfig
        })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleAuthService } from "ng-gapi";
import { GoogleApiService } from "ng-gapi";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test-gapi';

  constructor(private googleAuthService: GoogleAuthService, private gapiService: GoogleApiService, private _http:HttpClient){
    this.gapiService.onLoad().subscribe(resuult => {
      console.log(resuult);
    });
  }

  signIn(){
    this.googleAuthService.getAuth().subscribe( auth => {
      auth.signIn().then(() => {
        let access_token = auth.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',  'http://localhost:4200');
        console.log(access_token);
        this._http.get<any>('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections' + `&access_token=${access_token}`, {'headers' : headers}).subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
        })

      });
    });
  }
}
```

I have defined scope properly as well. I have even checked in google API explorer, we are not getting email even there. I fetched everything in result except email of all contacts. Please provide any suggestions or any other way out to get google contacts

Comment: Please provide what you did so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.   Make sure you have authorized the user with the email scope.

Comment: Since you are also getting this error in the API explorer its probably not useful for you to post your angular code. Can you post the http request and response that is generated by the API explorer?

Answer (score 0):

#### Sample request

```sh
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:listDirectoryPeople?readMask=emailAddresses&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Using the [`listDirectoryPeople`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople) method.

Returns a result like:

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "resourceName": "people/000000000000000000001",
      "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoCAQc=",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "verified": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
              "id": "000000000000000000001"
            }
          },
          "value": "email1@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceName": "people/000000000000000000002",
      "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoCAQc=",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "verified": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
              "id": "000000000000000000002"
            }
          },
          "value": "email2@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

- Uses the required "sources" as `DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE`
- Uses readmask as way to limit fields returned `emailAddresses` , can be used to return more fields, you would just need to comma separate them.